# Python3 Leap Year Calculator

Tags: debugging, python-3.x

Ok so I'm learning python3 and thought maybe trying out my first script with a leapyear calculator but I can't seem to figure out how to print if the current year is a leapyear or not much less calculate the next two.

Here's my code thus far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

#calculate if this year is a leap year and the next 2 leap years

from datetime import datetime

this_year=(datetime.now().strftime('%Y'))

def is_leap_year(year):
    if ((year % 4 == 0) and (year % 100 != 0)) or (year % 400 == 0):
        return "{0}, {1} is a leap year".format(True, year)
    return "{0} is not a leap year".format(year)

print(is_leap_year(this_year)
```

So could anyone point out my error(s) here?  Many thanks!

Comment: My apologies. I considered this but wasn't sure where to post. I figured there would be some astute reader who would surely offer correction, rather than address the actual question. My gratitude is endless.

Comment: No need for apologies. Thing is, you have better chance of finding programming-related answers there rather than here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a whole library of date manipulation routines and whatnot there, just use them:

```
try:
    datetime.date(2016, 2, 29)
    print("is leap-year")
except ValueError:
    print("isn't leap-year")
```

If the `date()` method is able to handle the 29th of February, it's a leap-year, otherwise not.

Comment: Thanks! This appears much simpler than my first attempt.